# The Link Checker Script for Google Ads is not sending me an Email Alert

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I am trying to implement the [link checker script](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/solutions/link-checker) for Google Ads in my account. The script runs successfully, the log is being updated. However, I do not receive any emails from the script even when I have the "Email even if no errors are found?" setting turned on in this [Google Sheet file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZaV8cegQ6TEJTQhVx69KmuwTCaeZp4lS-7apL0w0TJM/edit?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-9yF-UPmGJZvL1Rxpu9OLtg) it's connected to.

I tried running this snippet of code to see if I'd receive an email but still did not receive one. So I'm assuming the problem is that the MailApp service is not able to send emails to my address for whatever reason. Has anyone had a similar problem, or know the solution to this? Any help is much appreciated thanks!

```
function main() {
  MailApp.sendEmail("aldric.ang@emma-sleep.com",
                  "aldric.ang@emma-sleep.com",
                  "TPS report status",
                  "What is the status of those TPS reports?");
}
```